# Dúvida sobre o método onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, funções

Alguém poderia me explicar qual a finalidade desse método?

**onCreateOptionsMenu**

Já pesquisei em vários sites (na documentação do Android também), mas ainda assim não ficou claro qual a finalidade desse método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um dos métodos públicos disponíveis da Activity que podem ser sobrescritos. A finalidade dele é a de simples criação de menus de opções de uma Activity inflando um XML (Menu).

São os menus que geralmente ficam no topo ao lado direito do aplicativo.

Um exemplo de menu de opções do WhatsApp:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Notas:*

> - Esse método é chamado apenas uma vez após o método `onStart()` no ciclo de vida da Activity. Para tornar dinâmico a alteração de itens do menu com base em eventos durante o ciclo de vida da Activity você pode usar o método `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`
> - A exibição do menu pode variar em versões do android

---

**Mas porque usar as APIs de menu do Android?**

Apesar de você ter liberdade para criar algo do zero, usar as APIs disponíveis é recomendado pois, além de ser bem mais fácil de criar e dar manutenção, o usuário já está familiarizado com esse tipo de navegação.

---

*Relacionado:*

**onOptionsItemSelected()**

Método "ouvinte de cliques" do menu de opções. Com esse método você pode saber qual item do menu foi clicado e realizar ações específicas.

---

*Mais sobre:*

- [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)
- [Métodos públicos de Activitys](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#public-methods_4)